# How can i execute my exe file form server

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to keep my exe on Sever. And on Client Desktop icon for that application  will contain the address of that server whenever user will click on desktop icon it should call from server location on his computer. That exe should run on his computer. what should i use? How can achieve this. Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: You will need two exe's a client exe and a server exe the client exe talks to.

Answer (score 1):

You can use shared folder fo this.
Place exe file in the sared folder and create a shortcut.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are trying to accomplish.

If you are doing this so you can change the actual EXE without updating the users computer, then you would have a simple app on the users computer that would look for the exe on the server.  Once it found it, it could execute it via:

Process.Start(exeName) // where exeName is a reference to the executable you want to run, including path.

Once that has started, your app can now exit as it is no longer working.

Using this approach, you can have your app check for the exe of your choice and run that.

If you just want to be able to keep the exe on the server, then just click on the exe in the server (in windows explorer) and drag it to the users desktop as a shortcut and you are good to go.

Enjoy